# How should I set the LargeChange property of a scrollbar so the thumb is a proportional size for the Max value?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scrollbar, windows-forms-designer

Basically, I want my scrollbar to behave like a scroll panel scrollbar. What algorithm, given the min and max values, should I give to the large change so that the thumb sizes up with how the scroll bar in a panel would to its contents?

**EDIT:** What I'm looking for is like a, "it multiplies the maximum value by x.xx until xx" or something

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. How is a "scrollbar" different from a "scroll panel scrollbar"?

Comment: @Cody Gray  there is none, but an H or VScrollBar on its own will not set the large change automatically to work nicely with the min and max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scrollbar handles the thumb size automatically. Just figure out your scroll range and page size.

If you want other information, I recommend editing your question to make it less general.

Comment: Okay, well lets say it didn't do that :p, because I'm making my own GUI in c++ and I'm trying to emulate win form behavior

Comment: Then you would to figure out what percent the page size is of the total scroll range, and then make the thumb that same percent of the scrollbar.

Comment: @JonathanWood please look at this question i am sure you will know. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11136290/1356321